# After pressing tab on a website, how to get the html focused element's background and the border color?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to automate website accessibility checks for which I need to know the color contrast of the focused element(after the tab press) with its border color.

Approach:

1. Earlier I was trying to capture the screenshot of an entire website before and after the tab press.
2. Then I did image comparison using computer vision and cropped the image difference but this approach won't work on a website where content is dynamically changing.

So, I read about Chrome inbuilt behavior when the user presses the tab to enhance user accessibility experience (It adds border-color blue/orange/white over the focused component).
So I am looking for suggestions whether this can be done via HTML source code instead of image comparison.

In the following images, chrome adds the white border over the focused element whereas the background color is green.

[Before Tab Press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEn8T.png)

[After Tab Press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVGKZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS Pseudo class :focus, which comes into action when focus is put on a tab or form element in browser, each browser agent have some default focus rules which gets applied if one have not written custom focus rules for that element. So put short, you can do this using CSS :focus.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to get the background color using CSS selector :focus tag for the following website https://www.gov.uk/ but unable to get the background color even though I can easily see its yellow when I pressed the tab button. I tried to run the below code on the browser console.  `document.querySelector("*:focus")`. Am I doing something wrong here? (I need to get the background color of an element which gets focused when I press Tab).